# Cocos2dx importing QuartzCore framework gives (Reference to Point, Rect, Size is ambiguous) error

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, quartz-core, ambiguous

I am working on a cocos2dx game using c++. When ever I import the quartzcore framework into my header file, after building it gives me 20+ errors saying Point is ambiguous. the error only comes when i import the quartz file by writing this "#import ".
I have linked the framework in the "link with binary" so there should not be a linking issue.
any help is appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a c++ game in cocos you need to be careful to partition your Objective-C code from your C++ code.

The easiest way to do this is to only use #import in your .mm files (which can contain both C++ and Objective-C code) to ensure that you cannot get objective-C directives in your plain c++ side of the world.

Even so, this error should not happen if you are using namespaces in your c++ code correctly: While the Quartz framework - being Objective-C defines "Point" etc. in the global namespace, Cocos2d-x defines it Point in the cocos2d namespace.

So, if you place all your application code inside a namespace, and import the cocos namespace into that, you will avoid the global namespace collision you are getting.

In my app, for example, I use a namespace around all my c++ code somewhat like this:

```
namespace myapp {
  using cocos2d;

  class MyClass {
  public:
    Point cocosPoint;
    ::Point quartzPoint;
  };
}
```

Comment: hey Chris, sorry for not replying earlier. I forgot to mention that even if i write "#include<QuartzCore/CABase.h>, I get the same error. not sure what causing the reference to Point is ambiguous error.

Comment: the best guess I can make is that there must be some macro in the quartzCore framework that is messing with the existing application code, because the error only comes when you include the header.

Comment: The point is you should not #include that file from cpp, its an objective-C header file and should consequently always be #imported - just NEVER from a .cpp or a .h that is #included from .cpp.